# How to conditionally pick a row based on status value?

Tags: postgresql, query, duplication, condition, exclusion-constraint

I want to select all available and bought packs. An user can open two pages to buy one pack, this results in two rows in the payment table. One gets status 'Pending' and the one that is bought gets status 'Paid'. I created the code below to show all available and paid packs for 1 user.

```
select distinct p.id_pack, pa.status,
    CASE
        WHEN pa.status = 'paid' THEN 'Paid'
        WHEN pa.status = 'pending' THEN 'Available'
        WHEN pa.status ISNUll THEN 'Available'
        END Status2
from packs p
left join payment pa
on p.id_pack = pa.pack
left join users u
on u.id_user = pa.user
and u.cognito_id='x'
order by p.id_pack
```

**Current result**

| id_pack | status2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Paid |
| 2 | Paid |
| 2 | Available |
| 3 | Paid |

The third row (id_pack 2, status2 'Available') should **not** be selected because that pack has been bought by the user (That row is created because two buy pages had been opened).

**Expected result**

| id_pack | status2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Paid |
| 2 | Paid |
| 3 | Paid |

Anyone knows how to do this?

### **UPDATE**

I ran the code from jjanes. The result is under the image.

```
select p.id_pack,  u.id_user,
    max(CASE
        WHEN pa.status = 'paid' THEN 'Paid'
        WHEN pa.status <> 'paid' THEN 'Available'
        WHEN pa.status isnull then 'Available'
        END) as Status2
from packs p
left join payment pa
on p.id_pack = pa.pack
left join users u
on u.id_user = pa.user
and u.cognito_id='x'
group by p.id_pack, u.id_user
order by p.id_pack
```

[image]

Somehow it is creating two entries for each row and it transforms 'available' to 'paid'(?). I'm a bit clueless on why this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer to my problem.

```
SELECT allPacks.id_pack, allPacks.name, allPacks.price, allPacks.user, allPacks.discount, allPacks.preview_url, allPacks.type, allPacks.description,
    CASE
        WHEN allPaid.status = 'paid' THEN 'Paid'
        WHEN allPaid.status = 'pending' THEN 'Available'
        WHEN allPaid.status ISNUll THEN 'Available'
    END payment_status
FROM (select * from packs) as allPacks
left join (select * from packs pack, payment pay, users u 
    where pay.status='paid' 
    and pay.pack=pack.id_pack 
    and u.id_user=pay.user
    and u.cognito_id='x'
    and pay.user=1) as allPaid
    on allPacks.id_pack = allPaid.pack
```

For the people that responded, thank you :)

Comment: That `ISNUll` doesn't look right. Perhaps you meant `IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You could aggregate the status2. You would want to keep the max value (in most collations, maybe in all). Your join to users doesn't seem to do anything.

```
select p.id_pack, 
    max(CASE
        WHEN pa.status = 'paid' THEN 'Paid'
        WHEN pa.status = 'pending' THEN 'Available'
        WHEN pa.status ISNUll THEN 'Available'
        END Status2)
from packs p
left join payment pa
on p.id_pack = pa.pack
group by p.id_pack
order by p.id_pack
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your feedback. I appreciate it. Your code helped a bit, but not all the way.
Somehow, even if I include a join with the User Table, your code results in that IF a pack has been paid by any user, the status will be 'Paid'.
I can not include code/image here so I will update the question.